# iptables restart returns: Bad argument 'restart'

Tags: iptables

I have an `Ubuntu LTS` system running for a couple of years now.  Yesterday a power outage forced my computer down.  With power restored, I booted the system and everything seemed to start fine, with the exception of `iptables`.  Whenever I have rebooted this system, `ufw` always starts, even though I have configured it not to.  I prefer `iptables` simply because I know it, so I shut down 'ufw' and reconfigure `iptables` and restart it with the following procedure:

```
sudo ufw disable

sudo ip_tables_reset.sh
sudo ip_tables_config.sh

sudo iptables restart
```

and verify with

```
sudo iptables -S
```

which returns:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Now the line

```
sudo iptables restart
```

returns with

```
Bad argument 'restart'
```

But I have used this procedure faithfully for years now.  I have not installed any updates that I am aware of recently.

What has changed that this reliable method now fails?

**reference:**
iptables v1.4.12

Comment: do you have a file listing your rules ?  that is output from issuing sudo iptables-save   ... if so you can activate them by issuing ...  sudo bash -c "iptables-restore <  /full/path/to/my/rules/file  "

Comment: @ScottStensland - The rules are defined in the config script.  I will update my post with the rules I am using.

Comment: @ScottStensland - Using your suggestion fails with `iptables-restore: line 2 failed`.  Line 2 is `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mention this command

```
sudo iptables restart  #  wrong usage, its not a service
```

the below set of scripts is how you backup, enable or disable your firewall ... first verify you have the package installed

```
dpkg -l | grep iptables
```

one way to view current iptable settings

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

the canonical way to show current iptable rules (display only no changes)

```
sudo iptables-save
```

looking at your rules you are not blocking incoming traffic (your shields are down) whereas following does block all incoming traffic except specified ports

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [331:17104]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9727:1360720]
:GitHubWebHooks - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j GitHubWebHooks
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A GitHubWebHooks -s 192.30.252.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A GitHubWebHooks -j DROP
COMMIT
```

notice I open up a specific IP address 192.30.252.0/22 so I can run a server listening for incoming traffic so all mentions of GitHubWebHooks are optional ... if you save above into a file then load that file as your rules then you will be good to go ... shields up

before you change anything lets dump your current rules into an output file

vi firewall_save_current_rules.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash

set -o errexit  #  exit on error

#  dump current iptable rules to file

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

# ........

curr_timestamp=$(date '+%H%M%S%N')

curr_rulesfile=/etc/iptables/rules.v4.${curr_timestamp}.current_rules

rulesdir=$( dirname $curr_rulesfile )

if [[ ! -d $rulesdir ]]; then

    echo about to create dir $rulesdir
    mkdir $rulesdir
fi

iptables-save > ${curr_rulesfile}  # dump current iptable rules into output timestamped file


echo curr_rulesfile $curr_rulesfile
```

now execute above script to save your current iptable rules

```
sudo ./firewall_save_current_rules.sh
```

below code will define a new set of rules where we block all incoming traffic by default except specified parts (especially the ssh port + normal http and https ports)

vi firewall_shields_up.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash

set -o errexit  #  exit on error

#  create new set of iptable rules from inline list of rules - Block all incoming traffic by default except specified

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

# ........


curr_timestamp=$(date '+%H%M%S%N')

new_rulesfile=/etc/iptables/rules.v4.${curr_timestamp}.new_rules

rulesdir=$( dirname $new_rulesfile )

if [[ ! -d $rulesdir ]]; then

    echo about to create dir $rulesdir
    mkdir $rulesdir
fi

# .....  park into a new file below list of iptable rules

cat << EOF > ${new_rulesfile}

*filter
:INPUT DROP [331:17104]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9727:1360720]
:GitHubWebHooks - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j GitHubWebHooks
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A GitHubWebHooks -s 192.30.252.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A GitHubWebHooks -j DROP
COMMIT

EOF


echo new_rulesfile $new_rulesfile


iptables-restore <  ${new_rulesfile}  #  engage new iptable rules from file


echo here is new iptable settings

iptables-save


#  ... if you are running docker you will want to bounce its daemon
#  sudo service docker restart
```

execute above script to define new iptable rules

```
sudo ./firewall_shields_up.sh
```

for completeness below is a troubleshooting script which will effectively disable the firewall by opening up all incoming and outgoing traffic ... run in if you want an empty slate however run above firewall_shields_up.sh  to put back a proper firewall

vi firewall_shields_down.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash

set -o errexit  #  exit on error

#  open up all incoming and outgoing traffic ... effectively disabling the firewall

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

# ........ lets first backup current rules into timestamped file

curr_timestamp=$(date '+%H%M%S%N')

curr_rulesfile=/etc/iptables/rules.v4.${curr_timestamp}.current_rules_before_opening_up_all_traffic

rulesdir=$( dirname $curr_rulesfile )

if [[ ! -d $rulesdir ]]; then

    echo about to create dir $rulesdir
    mkdir $rulesdir
fi

iptables-save > ${curr_rulesfile}  # dump current iptable rules into output timestamped file

echo curr_rulesfile $curr_rulesfile

# ... now alter iptables to lower shield




iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F



# ... display new iptable rules

echo
echo following are the new iptable rules after we opened up all incoming and outgoing traffic
echo

iptables-save
```

Comment: Unless the hardware firewall that this server sits behind is compromised, all ports but 80 and 443 are blocked at said hardware firewall - I have physical access to server so port 22 is not necessary.  But, I appreciate your comprehensive analysis and will consider updating just as an added security layer - much obliged!   Having said that, I am confused, because I have literally used that  `sudo iptables restart` for better than 2 years and remember seeing the restart responses.  The procedure has been documented long ago.  Still researching and looking at how your answer fits.  Thank you!